# How to show that $x^t A x $ is divisible by $2$ where $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with all its diagonal entries are zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form

Let $A$ is a symmetric matrix with all diagonal element zero.

> How to show that the dot product of $x$ with $Ax$ is divisible by $2$
> ?

I can only verify for matrix of order (size) $2, 3, 4 $ but not sure about general $n×n$ matrix.

Edit: Here, $x$ is any vector in $\Bbb{Z}^n$.

If $A$ is  real  symmetric matrix with all diagonal elements $0$, then prove that $x^{T}Ax$ is divisible by $2$. ( Here $x$ is any vector in $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$, and $x^T$ denotes transpose of $x$ )

$2$nd edit: If $A$ is integer entry symmetric matrix with all diagonal elements $0$, then prove that $x^{T}Ax$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: Your question needs mor information, such as: What ist $x$, what is $A$? In particular, are the entries of $A$ integers? What do you mean by "divisible"? Also, use MathJax to typeset mathematical content.

Comment: Sorry, I am posting for first time, not even sure how to type mathematics character, x is any vector in R^n

Comment: There's a mathjax tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thank you, so much I got it.

Comment: And: Do you consider $x_1^2$  to be "divisible by two", or only $2 x_1^2$? If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, the statement is clearly wrong, because $\frac{1}{2}A$ is also smmetric with zeroes oin the diagonal.

Comment: yes, I think I got it. can you give me some time to make some edit..yes

Comment: Your specifications do have some problems. If $x\in\mathbb R^n$ the result of $\langle Ax, x\rangle$ must not even be integral. I believe you want to have $x\in\mathbb Z^n$ and $A\in\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a symmetric matrix with $a_{ii}=0$.

Then by symmetry $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$

Let $Q_A:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ is the quadratic form associated with $A$.

$\begin{align}Q(x) =x^TAx&=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_ix_j\\&=2\sum_{i\neq j, i>j}a_{ij}x_ix_j\end{align}$

If $A\in M_n(\Bbb{Z})$ and $x\in \Bbb{Z}^n$ , then clearly $2\mid Q(x) $

---

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&{\frac{1}{2}}\\ {\frac{1}{2}}&0\end{pmatrix}$

Then $\begin{align}Q(x) =x^TAx&= \frac{1}{2}x_1x_2+\frac{1}{2}x_2x_1\\&=x_1x_2\end{align}$

Clearly $2\mid Q(x) $ for all $x\in \Bbb{R^2}\setminus \{0\}$ is false.

---

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ {1}&0\end{pmatrix}$

Then $Q(x) =2x_1x_2$

Let $x=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$

Then $Q(x) =\frac{1}{2}$ and $2\nmid Q(x) $.

---

Hence $2\mid Q(x) $  if $a_{ij},x_i\in \Bbb{Z} $

Comment: Are you sure you have shown (in general) that $2|Q(x)$ implies that $a_{ij}, x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Thomas  My bad. I have shown if part.